# Sending options to a jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a third-party jQuery plugin with options that can be overridden. I have three files: the plugin source file, my Javascript file that sets the options I send to the plugin, and my HTML file that calls the script.

One of the options comes from an AJAX call, and to ensure that the option loads correctly, I load the script using $.getScript after the call returns. The rest of the options are static, so it's fine for them to stay in my script file.

Here is how I call the plugin from my HTML file after the script loads:

```
 $.("#plugin_selector").pluginName({newOption: ajaxValue});
```

Here is how I can successfully call the plugin from my Javascript file by sending an array of options (assuming that I load the script before the AJAX call):

```
var options = [{
    option1: value,
    option2: value2,
    option3: value3
});

$.("#plugin_selector").pluginName(options);
```

The problem is that when I load the script after the AJAX call and send the new option, all of the other options I set through my variable are overridden. Ideally, I want these two arrays combined.

How can I combine both the dynamic option sent from my HTML file and the array of options in my script file when calling the plugin? The options array from my Javascript file calls a few other functions within that file, so I thought it would be better to keep it inside of that Javascript file.

I have tried to follow this pattern: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/01/how-to-set-default-settings-in-your.html, but it does not work, I think because the third party plugin already performs the $.extend procedure when the plugin is called to override defaults.

Comment: I can't seem to understand the question exactly.. Do you instantiate the whole object, or are you just setting the option for a pre-instantiated object? Can you give some more code where you make the  $.("#plugin_selector").pluginName({newOption: ajaxValue}); call and the ajax function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to be sure without knowing the specific plugin you're dealing with, but I think you are nearly there and $.extend is what you want to do.

All [$.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) does is merge two objects together, and what you want to do is merge your initial static set of options with your ajax one.

I'm assuming that this line

```
$.("#plugin_selector").pluginName({newOption: ajaxValue});
```

Is called from the ajax success handler? If so try changing it to this.

```
//This is somewhere on your page (in scope of your ajax callback)
var options = {
    option1: value,
    option2: value2,
    option3: value3
    };


//This is inside your ajax callback
$.("#plugin_selector").pluginName($.extend(options, {newOption: ajaxValue});
```